# sshfs over mosh tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshfs, mosh

I am using `sshfs` over ssh tunnel. The reason for this is because I do not have direct access to machine from which I want to mount file system.

This command establishes me tunnel:

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -L 2222:192.168.1.55:22 root@beast -Nf
```

And this one mounts me remote file system

```
sudo sshfs -o idmap=user,allow_other,reconnect,TCPKeepAlive=no,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3 waktana@localhost:/home/wakatana /ubuntu -p 2222
```

The problem is that I am using unreliable link and this connection is often hanging (I am not able to access /ubuntu, text editor which has opened files from /ubuntu freezes etc.) despite the options that I've tried.

I've read about [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) that I would like to give a chance, but I do not know how can I create tunnel using `mosh`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> not yet possible. there is a pull-request for oob data which seems to
>   work for some people, though: [mosh/pull/583](https://github.com/keithw/mosh/pull/583)

all credits goes to guy named `tribut` from `#mosh` channel on `freenode`

Answer (score 1):

I see "complaints" that mosh doesn't support X11 tunneling; I don't expect it supports anything other than an interactive terminal.

*Might* get slightly nicer behavior in gnome programs if you use Files' 'connect to server' with url 'ssh://host'.  I.e. gnome vfs might handle hangs slightly better.  Or not.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use gnome but openbox and as I said the machine with desired FS is not directly accessible

Comment: Ah, sorry.  If you did use gnome, I guess you could hack something up in .ssh/config, maybe  'Match host' + ProxyCommand.

Comment: I find that gvfs has equivalent, or worse, performance than sshfs; Over slowish connections gvfs felt like it froze more often.