# File transfer over mosh

Tags: ssh, sftp, mosh

I am using `mosh` for my regular terminal based activities. However I have also remote file sever access (via `sftp`) in `nautilus`. (I am using Ubuntu 16.10 with unity).

(In `nautilus`, in the URL bar, I just type:

```
sftp://user:password@host:port/dir/to/enter
```

And then the entire (remote) filesystem is mounted...)

Is there anyway, I can mount this remote FS using `mosh`? A (possibly similar) [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205820/246619) gives a negative answer, however this is 2015 question and I am sure `mosh` has come a long way after that.

-- Mike

Comment: This isn't compatible with nautilus, but is rather mosh with an scp usage: https://github.com/mcginty/shoop